# How to scrape smiles from a messages in telegram channel with telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I scrape messages from a telegram channel with telethon

```
with TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash) as client:
   for message in client.iter_messages(chat):
      print(message.sender_id, ':', message.text)
```

and i have a problem with scrape interactive smiles from a messages, how i get to fix it?

Screenshot:
in a empty spaces should have been a interactive smiles from telegram

[image: ()]

I need this smile to scrape
[Interactive Dice Smile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v26jX.png)

Answer (score 2):

There is in telethon type 'InputMediaDice' with it you can catch all interactive emoticons

```
with TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash) as client:
   for message in client.iter_messages(channel_link, reply_to = post_num, filter = InputMediaDice('')):
       if type(message.media) == MessageMediaDice and message.media.emoticon == '' and message.media.value == 5:
           print(message.media.emoticon)
```